# sorting folders in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting

I am making a file manager application in flutter, when I sort files and folders by size, the files are sorted but the folders are not.

```
onlySortSize() async {
    controller.sortBy(SortBy.size);
}
```

```
Widget folderSize(FileSystemEntity entity) {
  return FutureBuilder<FileStat>(
    future: entity.stat(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (entity is File) {
          int size = snapshot.data!.size;

          return Text(
            FileManager.formatBytes(size),
          );
        } else if (entity is Directory) {
          String dosyaKonum = "$entity";
          String exDosyaKonum = extractTextBetweenSingleQuotes(dosyaKonum);
          int totalSize = 0;
          Directory folder = Directory('$exDosyaKonum');
          List<FileSystemEntity> files = folder.listSync(recursive: true);
          for (FileSystemEntity file in files) {
            if (file is File) {
              totalSize += file.lengthSync();
            }
          }
          return Text(
            FileManager.formatBytes(totalSize),
          );
        }
      } else if (entity is Directory) {
        return Text('data');
      }

      return const Text("aaaaaabbbccc");
    },
  );
}
```

------------the method I have sorted by size.
---------the method by which I calculate the size of the folder
[sorted out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWBCw.png)
How can I sort files and folders by size at the same time?

Comment: You have a different logic in the `if (entity is File) {` statement from the one in `else if (entity is Directory) {`. Don't you need to do it for both types?

Comment: The problem is not in the folderSize method, I'm sorting in the onlySortSize method, only the files are sorted. What should I do to get the folders to be sorted as well?